# Reduced image quality in Android as compared to Windows Operating System

Tags: android, image, opengl-es

I made a small program to display image in android using opengl and bitmap image.
The image quality displayed in my program was very degraded even if I didn't do any sampling  of the image in the decoding options.

After that I opened the same image in Android native gallery but even then it showed me low quality image as compared to same image opened in windows operating system.

I am using Windows-7 OS and Android OS version is Kitkat.
Is there any way to achieve the same image quality in Android OS also.

Comment: Poor quality? Different screens, different brightness levels, different algorithms to render the image, these all make a difference to the image displayed. I don't think Android deliberately worsens the quality of images

Answer (score 1):

your image gallery might be showing the image after reducing its size to fit the viewport. All android devices have different height to width ratio. So the gallery app might be adjusting its size to maintain the aspect ration of the image.